# Can ExtUtil::MakeMaker upon 'make install'

Tags: perl

I've been playing with MakeMaker and it seems to do everything I need except for one thing: at the end of `make install,` I need to run a shell command that registers the path of one of the modules installed to the tools my code integrates with:

```
 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/manage_hooks add script /path/to/ftBackup.pl --manual --category=System --event=Backup --stage=post
```

Where "/path/to/" should be where MakeMaker is intending to install the script listed in its `EXE_FILES` parameter.

Is that doable in a straightforward manner? Or have I hit the straightforward limit of MakeMaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the Makefile by defining a postamble method in your Makefile.PL.

```
sub MY::postamble {
    return <<'MAKE_FRAG';
install ::
        echo 'postinstall'
 
MAKE_FRAG
}
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Overriding-MakeMaker-Methods

Comment: Thank you. Would the commands I wanted to run just go after the `echo` line? Is there a best practice on how I'd refer to the path to where `EXE_FILES` have been installed?

Comment: Is this correct? `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/manage_hooks add script  $(INSTALLSITEBIN)/ftBackup --manual --category=System --event=Backup --stage=post` It seems to work, but I wasn't sure if I was mistaken to use `INSTALLSITEBIN`.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler 1) Whatever is returned from postamble is appended to the Makefile, so write it like you would any Makefile. 2) It's been quite some time since I've used MakeMaker. It will either be INSTALLBIN or INSTALLSITEBIN.

Comment: Thank you. INSTALLSITEBIN did the trick for where MakeMaker put the script. I appreciate the help!